# Uploading video file from Pi to Web Server

Tags: php, python, video, networking, upload

I'm trying yo upload video from raspberry pi to a web server. I'm able to upload an image, but using the same way to upload a video is not giving any output.

The code that I've used to upload an image is below:

```
import pi camera
from time import sleep

camera = camera.PiCamera()
camera.capture('preview.jpeg')

url = ".../camupload.php"
files = {'file' : open('preview.jpeg','rb')}

r = requests.post(url,files=files)
```

The server side `php` code I'm using is below:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
?>
```

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance

Comment: Any errors?  What does your `$_FILES` array contain?

Comment: it contains the video that I'm uploading. I used the same code to upload another video with less size, it did work!! but still there's a problem. I can't play the video. 
the extension is .h264

Comment: Right. Post an array_dump of the $_FILES array so we can see.  It may give you an error code (probably relating to max_upload_size).  Not being able to play is another issue.